# Wordpress "Allowed memory size" on wp-db.php

Tags: errors, memory

My web site keeps giving me this error:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /wwwroot/xxx/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1832`

How Can I fix this problem?

Comment: please explain the problem better. what you did to get this problem? regardless of your php settings, there is some script that is eating up resources. consider updating your plugins, or removing your plugins one by one.

Comment: I have wrote some plugins myself is there a way to check and see what is eating up the resources?

Comment: there were some plugins in the past that worked well, but not working well today. still you may try searching for "query monitor" or "monitor query" and check what's hot

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the php-memory-limit you can find out how much you have now with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Edit php.ini .Search "memory_limit" in your php.ini, and change the value of it. If no "memory_limit" found, add the following line at the end of php.ini
memory_limit = 128M ; /* Change the 128M to your needs */
Save file.

Edit : Or try in your wp-config.php, find or add the following line: define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');